# How to fix the upload server in jquery file upload with codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i'm try to make a images file uploader using jquery file upload and codeigniter, all things are good until i have to upload a file i use chrome to inspict the error it's show me that he can't fin the upload server

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: 'server/php/'
});
```

in the end how to fix it 
thanks

Comment: Show us some code about the view where you actually are uploading the picture.

Comment: try `url: '/server/php/'`

Comment: it's seems to work but my probléme now this part of code `// Upload server status check for browsers with CORS support:
        if ($.ajaxSettings.xhr().withCredentials !== undefined)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: './get_files',
                dataType: 'json', ` it show me the seem error like the previous one

Answer (score 0):

for calling the path use base_url or site_url before the file path.

for example,

```
url:'<?php echo site_url;?>/server/php/'
```

try this and reply me.

Answer (score 0):

*server/php* must be replaced by the **controller name** that contains the statement to load the *uploadhandler.php* file as a library or by the controller followed by the method name.

Using the [tutorial](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Latest-jQuery-File-Upload-easy-integration-with-codeigniter) in the [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki), you configure

```
url: 'fileupload/'
```

If the upload form is on a page generated by another controller, that is, in a method of another controller, then note that

http://example.com/[controller-class]/[controller-method]/

*[controller-class]* can be configured to have several breaks per "/" as /example1/example2/examle3/. Then you must go up the hierarchical level to access the method correctly:

```
url: '../../../fileupload/'
```